# how to change graphics.drawline opacity with trackbar to be able to see behind the WinForm?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to draw a line in a windows form and be able to change the opacity of the line with a track bar to be able to see what's behind the windows form under the the drawn line.

I've used `Graphics.DrawLines` to draw the line, and I've made a small method to draw the line so I can later call it in the `trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` method to be able to change the drawn line opacity

```
private void DrawArrowPoints(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    // Create pens.
    Pen redPen = new Pen(Color.FromArgb(trackBar1.Value, 255, 0, 0), 5);

    // Create points that define curve.
    Point point1 = new Point(200, 150);
    Point point2 = new Point(350, 25);
    Point point3 = new Point(500, 150);

    Point[] curvePointsSet = { point1, point2, point3 };

    // Draw lines between original points to screen.
    e.Graphics.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.GammaCorrected;
    e.Graphics.DrawLines(redPen, curvePointsSet);
}
```

I have two issues, the first issue is how do I call `DrawArrowPoints` in the `trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)` method. The second issue is how do I make the inside of my windows form to be transparent so that it only shows the line drawn and be able to change that line opacity with the trackbar

```
private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawArrowPoints(e); //This gives me an error because e is defined as EventArgs and DrawArrowPoints takes a PaintEventArgs
}
```

I've also tried this

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    DrawArrowPoints(e);
}
```

and I added `trackBar1.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.trackBar1_ValueChanged);` at the beginning of my `DrawArrowPoints` method but the form isn't transparent and I want the form to be active because when I set `this.BackColor = Color.Lime;` `this.TransparencyKey = Color.Lime;` in the `Form1_Load` the form becomes transparent but unclickable and I can't change the line opacity from the trackbar

Thank you in advance

Comment: 1) you can and should trigger the `Paint` event by doing an `Invalidate()`. in the `trackBar1_ValueChanged` .. but: 2) `TransparencyKey`  will work if and only if the colors match __100% including__ alpha!

Comment: Thank you for your reply, the `Invalidate()` in the `trackBar1_ValueChanged` worked and the opacity of the drawn line works great using the trackbar. But for 2) I'm still searching around about the alpha! My code has the following 
`DrawArrowPoints(PaintEventArgs e)` with the `trackBar1.Scroll += new System.EventHandler(this.trackBar1_ValueChanged);` added at the beginning of the method...
`private void trackBar1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Force the form to be redrawn with the image.
    this.Invalidate();
}`
and `DrawArrowPoints(e);` in the `Form1_Paint` method

Comment: Point 2) is a given. No way to really get around it. You may want to tell more about what the app is actually doing. Maybe capturing the background and displaying in the form could emulate the effect..

Comment: I've captured the background in another app and displayed it but for some reason sometimes it flickers so I was looking if I could just have a transparent form where I can still use my trackbar and see through my transparent drawn lines and change the line's opacity using the trackbar

Comment: TrackBar is a control that is provided by the OS, the .NET wrapper class merely lets you set properties.  It does its own painting and does not support any kind of owner-draw.  So this cannot work, you'd have to create your own control by deriving from the Control class.  Not impossible, and has been done many times before, find hits by googling "windows form custom trackbar control".  "Slider" is another common name.

Comment: @Hans: I don't think he wants anything special from the trackbar beyond providing a number for alpha. He tried to make parts of the form semi-transparent, which won't work the way he tried, i.e. by drawing transparency..

Comment: _but for some reason sometimes it flickers_ I don't see the code; flickering forms should have `DoubleBuffered = true`.

Comment: @Hans TaW is right all I want from the trackbar is a number for alpha and the line transparancy now works from the trackbar my issue now is how to make the background of the form to be able to see what's behind my form here is my code

Comment: @Hans, TaW is right all I want from the trackbar is a number for alpha and the trackbar issue is solved my issue now is how to make the background of the form to be able to see what's behind my form. In my old app I used a timer to capture the screen and display it in a picturebox

Comment: myBitmap = new Bitmap(640, 512);
                            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(myBitmap))
                            {
                                g.CopyFromScreen((screens[0].Bounds.X), (screens[0].Bounds.Y), 0, 0, myBitmap.Size, CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);;
                            }
pictureBox1.Image = myBitmap;